# How to show that $I$ = {f $\in$ $F(X,R)$ : $f(a)=0$ $\forall a \in A$} is an ideal of $F(X,R)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am studying ring theory and have come across a ring:

$F(X,R)$ ={all functions $X \to R$} with $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(f \times g)(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$ with $X$ a nonempty set.

There is a question:

Show that, for $A \subset X$ the subset $$ I = \{ f \in F(X,R) : f(a)=0 \forall a \in A \} $$ is an ideal of $F(X,R)$.

I have found that an ideal is a subring of a ring which is closed under R-multiplication.

I think that I need to use the subring test to first show that $I$ is a subring and then show that $I$ is closed under R-multiplication, but I am confused about showing that $I$ is closed under R-multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in I$ and let any $g\in F(X,R)$. Then for each $a\in A$ we have $(gf)(a)=g(a)f(a)=g(a)\times 0=0$. Hence $gf\in I$. Similarly you can show that $fg\in I$.